# Reading Custom Attributes of a .Net class property in Javascript

Tags: javascript, .net, reflection, properties, custom-attributes

I have a .Net class with some properties. In some of the properties, I use Custom Attributes. For e.g.

```
   <UserDefined(true)>_
   Property Name as string
```

I Use webservices and JSON to retrieve an instance of this class on my web-forms client side and use Java-script extensively. Is there a way in Java-script object to identify whether a Property has any Custom Attribute defined and its value? I tried Property Description of the Object class in JS, but it just gives the property name and its value, not any Attributes of that Property.

Comment: the only way that could ever happen is if the javascript is running in a scripting layer that has direct access to the .NET type system and access to the relevant .NET process, which seems *extremely* unlikely, so *unless* you're doing something very unusual: "no". The only thing it will have access to is the data in the json, which will be simply: `... "Name": "Fred" ...` - nothing more